# Why is this the axis of the given linear transformation? (Geometry)

Tags: geometry

We have given a projective plane $ (P, G) = PG(2, \mathbb{R}) $ and a linear transformation:
\begin{equation}
f_1: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, x \mapsto \left( \begin{matrix}
1 &0&1\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&2
\end{matrix}\right) x
\end{equation}

And are supposed to calculate the center (by definition the point where all lines trough that point are fixed point lines, $f_1(l) =l$ for all $l$ on such a line) and the axis of $f_1$. We got the solution from our professor: the axis is the eigenspace of the eigenvalue 1, that means
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{R}(1, 1,1)^T + \mathbb{R} (1,-1,0)^T
\end{equation}

And as a center
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{R}(0,1,-1)^T
\end{equation}

But we don’t get to that, can someone verify that solution? And help us out on that?